# Program to count number of digits in a double following decimal point in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, double, precision, floating-accuracy

Below is a program that is supposed to count the number of digits in a double value following the decimal point. On entering some double values, the program tends to start an infinite loop (possibly due to floating-point imprecision). I **do not** want to use any wrapper methods (including String class). Could someone possibly provide an explanation for the endless loop for certain inputs and provide a solution?

```
import java.util.*;
class Flt
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter a double number: ");
        double f = sc.nextDouble();
        double tmp = f;
        
        int len = 0;
        while(tmp != (int) tmp)
        {
            tmp *= 10;
            len++;
        }
        System.out.println(len);
    }
}
```

Comment: One very likely reason for this would be floating point precision issues. The easiest and most robust solutions would actually be to use `BigDecimal` or a string representation. Other than that you could try to compare the values using a threshold (i.e. consider them equal if the absolute difference is smaller than, let's say 0.0000001 - you'd need to find a reasonable value). Note, howevevr, that even a single calculation that involves `double` can already change the fraction digits (0.12345 * 10 already is 1.2345000000000002).

Comment: Java’s `double` format uses a binary floating-point format, so it does not properly have any decimal places. Attempting to count decimal places is a misunderstanding of how floating-point arithmetic works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem overflows in the conversion to `int`, so `tmp != (int) tmp` is never true.

Consider a user input of “3.1415”. 3.1415 is not representable in the `double` format, so it is converted to the nearest representable value, 3.141500000000000181188397618825547397136688232421875. First, this has so many decimal digits that, even if the multiplications by ten were performed with exact real-number arithmetic, they would not produce an integer result until the number reached 3141500000000000181188397618825547397136688232421875. However, that number cannot be converted to `int` without overflow, because it is too large to be represented in an `int`. The conversion yields the largest value representable in `int`, 2147483647. Then comparing the number 3141500000000000181188397618825547397136688232421875 to the result of the conversion, 2147483647, indicates they are unequal, and the loop continues.

In fact, the multiplications by ten are not performed with exact real-number arithmetic. In each multiplication, the result is rounded to the nearest value representable in `double`. So the first yields 31.415000000000002700062395888380706310272216796875, the next 314.15000000000003410605131648480892181396484375, and so on. The first integer result is 31415000000000004. Again, this is too large to represent in an `int`, so `tmp != (int) tmp` is evaluated as `31415000000000004 != 2147483647`, which is of course true, so the loop continues.

The infinite loop can be resolved by eliminating the conversion to `int`. For example, the test expression can be replaced by `tmp % 1 != 0` to loop as long as `tmp` has a remainder when divided by 1 (hence is not an integer). However, then an input of “3.1415” yields 16—it does not count the number of decimal places in either the user’s input or the `double` that results from scanning it but rather the number of iterations until the multiplications with rounding yield an integer.

Once the user’s input has been converted to a `double`, there is no way to properly count the number of decimal places in the user’s input because the original value is lost. If the user enters either “3.1415” or “ 3.141500000000000181188397618825547397136688232421875”, the resulting `double` will be 3.141500000000000181188397618825547397136688232421875, so it is not possible to tell what the original number was. To count the number of decimal places in the user’s input, reading it as a string, looking for the decimal point, and count the digit characters after it (excluding trailing zeros if desired).

Comment: So, just to confirm, there is no foolproof way of calculating number of digits in a real number by mathematical statements? I must use String to cope with the imprecision?

Comment: @millionleafclover: Once a number is converted to a `double`, it is possible to count the number of significant digits in a decimal representation of the `double` value, but it is not possible to know how many digits were in the original number, prior to its conversion and rounding to the nearest `double`.